# Delay with Thread.Sleep is causing issues when producing Timestamps in C#

Tags: c#, timestamp, thread-sleep

due to a project I'm generating some synthetic Data for building up a infrastructure for analysing purposes.

The infrastructure is build up with the data simulation for generating synthetic data. This data is send via UDP to node-red server and afterwards handed over via mqtt to kafka.

I simply generate a boolean combined with a timestamp. Now I want to analyse the time bewtween those timestamps. The data should be generated with some time in bewtween. So here's an example:

```
Data A:
{
isActivated: false,
Timestamp: "xxxxx"
}

Data B:
{
isActivated: true,
Timestamp: "xxxxx+deltaTime"
}
```

So `B.Timestamp-A.Timestamp = deltaTime`. So far so good, but when I'm adding a `Thread.Sleep(delay)`, the delay will be added to the deltaTime calculated from Kafka-Consumer... (I got the right Timestamps in the message for calculation, not those which produced from kafka itself. I tested it by adding 2 Days to the produced Timestamps in the DataGenerator)

So here the code-example:

```
public class CustomData
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public bool isActivated { get; set; }
}


public class DataGenerator 
{
    private bool DataAActivated { get; set; }
    private IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
    private UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
    private IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, XXXXX);
    
    public DataGenerator (bool dataAActivated)
    {
         DataAActivated = dataAActivated;
    }

    public void GenerateData(double delay, int deltaTime) 
    {
        DateTime ts0 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime ts2 = ts0.AddMilliseconds(deltaTime);
    
        if (DataAActivated) 
        {
            CustomData dataA = new CustomData();
            dataA.isActivated = false;
            dataA.Timestamp = ts0;

            CustomData dataB = new CustomData();
            dataB.isActivated = true;
            dataB.Timestamp = ts2;
        } 
        else
        {
            CustomData dataB = new CustomData();
            dataB.isActivated = false;
            dataB.Timestamp = ts0;

            CustomData dataA = new CustomData();
            dataA.isActivated = true;
            dataA.Timestamp = ts2;
        }
    
        // this is causing issues
        Thread.Sleep((int)delay);

        SendData(dataA);
        SendData(dataB);
    }
    
    private void SendData(CustomData data)
        {
            udpClient.Connect(iPEndPoint);

            byte[] jsonUtf8Bytes;
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                WriteIndented = true
            };
            jsonUtf8Bytes = System.Text.Json.
                              JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(data, options);
            
            udpClient.Send(jsonUtf8Bytes,jsonUtf8Bytes.Length);
            udpClient.Close();
        }
}
 
---------------- within Kafka-Consumer ----------------
public double CalcDuration( CustomData dataA, CustomData dataB)
{
    double duration = dataB.Timestamp.Subtract(dataA.Timestamp).TotalMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine($"duration: {duration}");
    return duration;
}
```

the output would look like this if the deltaTime would be 100 ms, and the delay 500ms
without line with Thread.Sleep(delay):

```
duration: 100ms
duration: 100ms
...
```

with Thread.Sleep(delay):

```
duration: 600ms
duration: 600ms
...
```

Does anybody has a hint for me how to fix this?

I hope i could make it clear, but don't hesitate to make me aware of editing this post.

Thanks a lot,

Greetings

Comment: I think we'll need more context i.e. how is `GenerateData` called?

Comment: It's not possible for the code you posted to behave as you describe. Your code explicitly adds `deltaTime` to the previously-initialized `ts0` value, so `ts2` is always and necessarily going to be different, by the `deltaTime` amount, and adding a call to `Thread.Sleep()` isn't going to change that. If you want help, please fix your question so that it includes a proper [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for your fast reply. Adding the whole usecase isn't that easy, beacause it's a distributed system with the DataSimulation, Node-Red-Server, MQTT-Broker, Kafka and .Net-Producers, Consumers.

Comment: Have to agree with @PeterDuniho, the problem is most definitely not in the code you've shown. Tip: Put a breakpoint or a print statement in your SendData method and you will see that the timestamps are as you expect them to be.

Comment: _"Adding the whole usecase isn't that easy"_ -- no one, least of all me, wants or expects you to "add the whole usecase". What we _do_ expect is for you to put sufficient effort into presenting your question so that a proper [mcve] is included which reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MarianTheisen Thanks for your reply. That's why it is so weird. I did exactly what you said. Calculating the time with Output on console on data generation side. But nevertheless this line is causing the problem. So I totaly agree that the failure has to be somewhere else, but I wanted to ensure that by asking that question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks again, and I agree that there should be a reproducible example. But for that I have to include all those things, because as you and Marian mentioned, the failure ist not in the code above. 

Maybe I'll try to come up with a docker-compose file and instructions for it. It is definitly a help to ensure that the problem is not in that part of code. So this helps me quite a lot. I will add Sequence numbers to verify twice that the correlated data on consumer side are those I expect. After that I'll will edit the question again.

Comment: _"Maybe I'll try to come up with a docker-compose file and instructions for it"_ -- sorry, but that would be entirely inappropriate for the Stack Overflow site. Your question really does need to be entirely self-contained, with a _text_ version of a proper [mcve] that can reliably reproduce the problem. If you cannot produce such an example for the question, then the question really just isn't appropriate for the site. Please keep in mind: not _every_ question anyone might imagine belongs here. SO deal with a broad, but still specifically constrained, _subset_ of all possible questions.

Comment: @PeterDuniho All right. I'll try to figure it out. Sorry for my unapropriate behaviour in asking my question. It is my first one and I already thought it would be difficult to ask the question. So thanks for your explanations how to get on the right track in asking questions. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue. As Peter and Marian mentioned there is no failure caused by the code I've posted in the question.

This brought me up to get through the code of the other services. By cleaning up the whole kafka-cluster related topics and starting to produce again, I saw that in the second service of the Producer/Consumer chain I set up the initial state wrong.

So the first message was skipped and therefore the calculation between the timestamps was one before the delay an one after. Thats because of a constraint I set for calculation of duration to be from the same offset.

so to make that clear:
data which is send to kafka arrives in topic "ingestion"
Messages there will be like this:

```
ingestion:
(1)dataA
(2)dataB
(3)dataA
(4)dataB
...
```

From that I dispatch those into two topics "activated", "notActivated" because the timestamp from notActivated data is everytime greater than from activated. To ensure that no packet loss or something happend I proof it by holding the last state (related to isActive attribute from CustomData) in the dispatcher. And that sate was initialy set wrong, so what happened is:

```
notActivated:
(1)dataA //--> this entry was not there because it was skipped refering to false state matching
(4)dataB

activated:
(2)dataB
(3)dataA
```

so the calculation of duration was

```
duration = (4)dataB - (2)dataB
```

and because of that the duration was:

```
duration = deltaTime + delay
```

Thanks a lot again to Peter and Marian

maudeees